# ListView adapter using simple_list_item_multiple_choice, check boxes do not work

Tags: android, listview

I am working with a search activity which extends ListActivity. I initialize my adapter as follows,

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, testArrayList);
    l.setAdapter(adapter);
```

However, I am not sure how to get the checkboxes to work. I have an onListItemClick method which works fine for clicking an actual list item.

```
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Log.d("Test", testArrayList.get(position));
    MainActivity test = new MainActivity();
    test.addToArray(testArrayList.get(position));
}
```

Comment: You need to create custom adapter to handle event on check box in list

Comment: in the getView() method of adapter add OnCheckedChangeListener to your checkBoxes. Also do not forget to turn focusableInTocuhMode true.

Comment: `MainActivity test = new MainActivity()` creating an instance of activity class. wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create custom adapter to handle event on check box in list

Answer (score 0):

First Create custom adapter & In getView() method of custom adapter use below code:

```
    itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check);

    ((CheckBox) (checkbox)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CheckBox c = (CheckBox) view;
            // your code

        }
    });
```